# Failed to transform artifact 'support-v4-25.1.0.aar (:support-v4-25.1.0:)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I built my unity project to android but it has some error on gradle, so I decided to export it to Android studio
but when I export it I get the following error :

```
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':unityLibrary@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'support-v4-25.1.0.aar (:support-v4-25.1.0:)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: unityLibrary
```

this is my build.gradle for unityLibrary

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.asynclayoutinflater.asynclayoutinflater-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.coordinatorlayout.coordinatorlayout-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.core.core-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.cursoradapter.cursoradapter-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.customview.customview-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.documentfile.documentfile-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.drawerlayout.drawerlayout-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.fragment.fragment-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.interpolator.interpolator-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.legacy.legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.legacy.legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager.localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.print.print-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.slidingpanelayout.slidingpanelayout-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout.swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.versionedparcelable.versionedparcelable-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'androidx.viewpager.viewpager-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'animated-vector-drawable-25.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appcompat-v7-25.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'arcore_client', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-17.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-17.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-api-17.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-17.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-impl-17.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-sdk-17.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-sdk-api-17.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-stats-17.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-17.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-17.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-app-unity-6.14.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-auth-19.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-auth-interop-19.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-auth-unity-6.14.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-19.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-components-16.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-database-19.2.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-database-collection-17.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-database-unity-6.14.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-20.0.2', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-interop-17.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-18.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-storage-19.1.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-storage-unity-6.14.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.mapbox.android.unity-debug', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'mapbox-android-telemetry-2-1-0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-compat-25.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-core-ui-25.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-core-utils-25.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-media-compat-25.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-v4-25.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-vector-drawable-25.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'unityandroidpermissions', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'UnityARCore', ext:'aar')
    implementation project('Firebase')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }
}
```

gradle.properties :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Android studio version : 3.5.
Gradle version : 5.4.1.

I cleaned the project and rebuilt but not works

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was that Mapbox SDK already included this file. I fixed it by removing all **.aar** files from `\Assets\Mapbox\Core\Plugins\Android`

Answer (score 0):

Close Android studio then

```
1)Go to C:Users:<OrgName>: .android - delete 'cache' folder.
2) Go to C:Users:<OrgName>: .gradle- delete 'caches', 'daemon' and wrapper folder.
```

then restart Android studio. It should work.